# C# or .Net client for RESTLET

Tags: .net, rest, restlet

I want to make use of RESTlet RESTful web-services.

The architechture will make use of a Java Based Server and Windows Forms (.Net) client.

I want to know if there is an easy way to convert the RESTlet xml to something .Net understands, maybe a 3rd party library?

It would be great to have wsdl tipe functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WDSL type functionality or SOAP is not related to RESTlet... 
The Restlet XML defines the internal workings of your RESTful server, how to concatenate Filters, Resources, Redirectors etc. It says nothing about client communication. Per definition, the REST client uses the HTTP protocol and its methods as the communciations protocol to access resources living on well defined URLs.

You can communicate with a REST server using the C# or .Net HTTP client.

You negotiate the content-type you want using the HTTP headers.
For example, your request could hold a header Content-Type: application/xml to ask the RESTlet server to send you XML back.